# Mixing two vectors: [a a] and [b b] to [a b a b]

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

How can I mix two given vectors to a new one, which holds their values in an alternating order.

```
(f [a a] [b b]) ; > [a b a b]
```

This comes to my mind:

```
(flatten (map vector [:a1 :a2] [:b1 :b2]))
```

But maybe there's an easier way.

Comment: by the way, there is a `mapcat` function, to avoid flattening: `(mapcat vector [:a1 :a2] [:b1 :b2])` . But for sure, `interleave` is definitely better

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `interleave`:

```
(interleave [:a :a] [:b :b])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```
(apply into (map vector [:a1 :a2] [:b1 :b2]))
```

`interleave` is the way to go though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use destructuring:

```
((fn [[a1 a2] [b1 b2]] [a1 b1 a2 b2]) [1 2] [3 4])
;[1 3 2 4]
```